# User with two 100-point bounties but no rep?

Tags: support, bounty

Why is this 1-rep user able to offer two 100-point bounties?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/979331/user979331?tab=bounties

Is there a bug in the bounty system?

Comment: Isn't the rep removed immediately? So the user has offered all their rep in bounties which still need to expire.

Comment: @Script47 Is that true? Looking at the user's history, it doesn't look to me like two days ago the user had 200 points of rep. But that's what I'm asking: did he?

Comment: @matt They did. The user has had over 10,000 reputation, they've just given it all away in bounties.

Comment: @animuson Foolishly. But I guess we can't do anything about _that_. So there's no hanky-panky here? That's all I really wanted to know.

Comment: Well, he used to have enough rep.  Seems he's trying to earn it back by accepting answers, fairly unique approach :)

Comment: I'm wondering if he can unaccept these answers (which will not put him below 1 reputation), and reaccept them (to fuel more bounties).

Comment: @HansPassant The question is whether there is something suspicious / underhanded / illegal about this approach. That is why I'm calling attention to it. Is there some sort of hole in the rules enforced by the site, or is this just a reasonable way of playing the game?

Comment: Looks kosher to me, he's not doing what Glorfinder is worried about.  Burning up all earned rep on bounties is not unusual at all.

Comment: @Glorfindel: in theory, they can do that yes. In practice, we will suspend accounts pulling such tricks. This user has not resorted to it, at any rate (you'd see the unaccepts on the reputation tab too, even if they result in 0 reputation change).

Answer (score 5):

By my guess and research, the user had 201 rep, or really less but then gained more to get to 101 before the second bounty, then placed the two 100 point bounties. They had enough rep for them, and bounties can be placed from when you have 75 rep on.

Looking at their rep history, this makes sense. The rep for a bounty is removed as soon as you place the bounty. On the 25th, the user in question placed the bounty. (The only odd part there is that it's listed as "-94" instead of "-100" but that would be fore a different question.

From there, they earned rep every day until they posted another 100 rep bounty today. This user apparently loves to give bounties- Looking at their offered bounties, they've given away 10k+ rep in bounties.

Comment: Today alone, they accepted 23 posts in order to build up the rep to start the bounty. check rep history

Comment: Well, now my question is pinned down by this answer while others take potshots at it. If you'll delete the answer, I'll delete the question.

Comment: There's no need to delete good information, @matt. It's not like you lose rep for downvotes here. I suggest letting it stand.